# How to display JSON data in proper format on GET request

Tags: python, django

I have created small API in django and Python. I am reading data from URL(Remote API) and storing into database when I do the GET request. Everything looks good and I am displaying same data on my server's endpoint as well.But it display in non readable format.

Please refer the below code view.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from customer.models import Customers
from .serializers import CustomersSerializer, CustomersKeySerializer
import json
import urllib.request
import pyodbc
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def customer_get(request):
    j = urllib.request.urlopen("https://web.njit.edu/~jsd38/json/customer.json")
    customer_data = json.load(j)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=DAL1281;"
                      "Database=Test;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT CustomerId FROM dbo.Customers")
    CustomerIdRows = [x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]

    CustomerIds = Customers.objects.values_list('CustomerId', flat=True)

    for customer in customer_data:
        CustomerId = customer["@Id"]
        Name = customer["Name"]
        PhoneNumber = customer["PhoneNumber"]
        EmailAddress = customer["EmailAddress"]
        StreetLine = customer["Address"]["StreetLine1"]
        City = customer["Address"]["City"]
        StateCode = customer["Address"]["StateCode"]
        PostalCode = customer["Address"]["PostalCode"]

        if int(CustomerId) not in CustomerIds:
            cus = Customers()
            cus.CustomerId = CustomerId
            cus.Name = Name
            cus.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber
            cus.EmailAddress = EmailAddress
            cus.StreetLine = StreetLine
            cus.City = City
            cus.StateCode = StateCode
            cus.PostalCode = PostalCode
            cus.save()

        if int(CustomerId) not in CustomerIdRows:
            cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO dbo.Customers(CustomerId,Name,EmailAddress,StreetLine,City,StateCode,PostalCode) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            (CustomerId,Name,EmailAddress,StreetLine,City,StateCode,PostalCode))
        cnxn.commit()
    queryset = Customers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomersSerializer
    return HttpResponse(customer_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you printing the json?

Comment: I suggest you check out Django Serializers. You wrote a lot of code for something that Django already does.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I posted the answer. But please also follow programming tips I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Rest Framework provides `Response` instead of `HttpResponse` to render json data as you intended.

use it like this:

```
...
return Response(customer_data)
```

and import it from here:    `from rest_framework.response import Response`

#### Some programming tips:

I saw your code and I think you can make it much cleaner and more readable and reduce redundantly sections as follow:

- use `setattr` to assign items. for example `setattr(cus, 'Name', nameValue)`
- get key's value of a json like this: `customer.get('EmailAddress', '')`, With this method if there is no key in that json for `EmailAddress` at least you can set a default value, else an exception will happen!
- use django orm and db connection. I don't think it's cool to use **RAW** queries in 2019 :). By the way, your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**, because you are passing unvalidated data from external json API to your database query right away. I don't suggest that at **ALL**.
- Avoid writing a variable that never used. For example `serializer_class`. Also I suggest render the response from you database. for example `return Response(serializer_class(many=True).to_representation(queryset)`